# Image not loading in tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am attempting to display an image from a file in my program. The python file is in the same folder as my image file and I have the file name correct. When it displays on the screen, the space is taken up where the image should be, but no image shows.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import tkinter as tk

cardImageLabel=Label(playerFrame, image=tk.PhotoImage(file="2C.png")).grid(row=1, column=0)
```

This is my code, it's a bit ugly and I should separate it but I'm more used to formatting it like this.

Comment: For the same reason they don't show up as discussed in [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function) — and has the same solution.

Comment: Your example is incomplete. Is the cod that uses the image inside a function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a reference to the image, to prevent collecting it by garbage collector, as there is no reference created to this object by PhotoImage class itself.

```
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="2C.png")
```